# Calling R-UDF's from Excel

Tags: r, excel, interface, user-defined-functions, r.net

I want to have functions in Excel (Taking Excel-Arguments) that call R-Functions and return the results back to Excel. RExcel does not seem to be on CRAN (anymore) and I have not yet found an alternative. Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

One constraint is that the solution should work even without administrator privileges on Windows Vista.

Edit:
Thanks for the comment. We have tried R.Net, but with little success. We went for:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ExcelDna.Integration;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using RDotNet;
using RDotNet.NativeLibrary;

public static class MyFunctions
{
    [ExcelFunction(Description = "Test R connection")]
        public static double MyRTest(double x)
        {
            var envPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
            var rBinPath = @"D:\Programme\R\R-2.15.1\bin\i386";
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", envPath + Path.PathSeparator + rBinPath);
            // using (REngine engine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet"))
            // {
            // }

            // REngine rengine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet");
            return (2*x);
        } // End Function


    [ExcelFunction(Description="Multiplies two numbers", Category="Useful functions")]
    public static double MultiplyThem(double x, double y)
    {
        return x * y;
    }
}
```

The function MultiplyThem() can be Called in Excel and it works. As is, so does MyRTest. But as soon as I try to instanciate R using either of the methods commented out, it returns the #Value error in Excel. Trying to make sense of it, we went for a Command Line application and just copied the example from [here](http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/) (v1.5). However at the line `engine.Initialize();` the debugger just terminated, without error or exception. We use R12.15.1 (32 Bit), Windows Vista (32 Bit), Visual Studio 2010 Professional and RdotNet 1.5.0. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: I don't think RExcel was ever on CRAN. It is offered by a group that charges a fee for some of its services. I think there is also another product going by the name of R.NET that may offer facilities but I think it also something you license for a fee. I also expect any product installation would require administrator privileges.

Comment: It is at [this site](http://rcom.univie.ac.at/) in Vienna.  They also have (had?) one large installer which bundled RExcel with R.